# Do I use TD-IDF correctly over corpus of raw documents?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am in doubt as to whether I use my TD-IDF calculations correctly. I have a large corpus of different documents, each document is stored in it's own row using pandas dataframe. I feed each row to TD-IDF in scikit-learn and store `feature_names` (words) in a list.

I am using following code:

```
term_tdidf = []

def tdidf_f(vec, matrix):
    f_array = np.array(vec.get_feature_names())
    t_sort = np.argsort(matrix.toarray()).flatten()[::-1]
    n = 100
    top_term = f_array[t_sort][:n]
    term_tdidf.append(set(top_term))

for row in df.document:
        x = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
        tfidf_matrix = x.fit_transform(row)
        terms = x.get_feature_names()
        tdidf_f(x, tfidf_matrix)
```

After that I create new dataframe where each set of tdidf from each document is stored in a separate column.

Is that correct use of TD-IDF? I am running it only on single document, so terms I am getting are only calculated within this one document, correct? As I understand td-idf should be used across all documents to find one set of frequent terms, not multiple sets. Are there any consequences of such application?

My manual review of extracted features from each document indicates that terms I am getting are fitting. Afterwards I am using those terms to calculate similarity between documents and it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the IDF part of the weighting, you need to count the number of times the term occurs in the whole corpus, so your code is incorrect.

Here is a minimal example of how to use it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

corpus = ["My first document", "My second document"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

`X` is then a matrix where each row is a document and each column represents a term.

Comment: That was my intuition. So what frequency is returned when done on single document? How I can correctly implement it to get frequency from one document against X number of other documents and then move to next one and, again, compare it against others.

Comment: You just need to iterate over the rows of ``X`` (each row is a document) and process as you did (on the row instead of ``matrix``). When done on a single document, the IDF term does not make sense: the purpose of the IDF term is to reduce the importance of the most frequent terms in the whole corpus since they are less discriminative. The IDF value is multiplied by the TF value which is the number of occurrences of the term in the current document.

Comment: I get your point now, especially after seeing difference myself. I calculate only term frequency when it's ran on single document. Considering that I want to find similarity between documents and running TD-IDF on list with all of documents inside brings me most frequent terms across all documents, I understand that using TD-IDF for inter document similarity is pointless (compare docA to docB to docC). Should I just use most frequent terms, different algorithm or run TD-IDF for each paragraph against whole document to get it accurate?

Comment: A common practice is to compute the similarity between documents by first transforming the documents to TF-IDF vectors (``X``) and then compute cosine similarity between vectors. This can be done with ``S = X @ X`` (since the rows in ``X`` are already normalized) which produces a matrix of similarity: ``S[i, j] is a similarity score between document ``i`` and document ``j``.

Comment: I think I get it, but last follow up question. How this vector holds (sorts?) each term to each document to compute similarity later? I mean, how do we know what terms is from what document. From what you are writing it seems like what is happening is document is transformed to vector of terms and then we are just comparing each vector against another to find distance between them. Could you update your answer with some sample code?

Comment: When comparing two vectors ``d1`` and ``d2``, ``d1[j]`` and ``d2[j]`` are the weights of ``d1`` and ``d2`` for the same word. The cosine of ``d1`` and ``d2`` is the sum over ``j`` (column or word) of ``d1[j] * d2[j]``. So when they both have a big value for a word, it increases the similarity. When one is small (near 0) the product is small so the contribution to the similarity is small.